# Explain some of the parameters in this Word macro to me

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was using code at the bottom that I found on the Internet to add commands to the Word 2013 right-click menu. Now that I have used it I was hoping to understand it better and could someone explain some of the parameters to me. I want to understand it better and case I want to run it again to add more commands. The official Microsoft help reference only confuses me.

How does `Before:=30` work? At first I thought it simply counted down from the top of the right-click menu, but when I did this my commands wound up in the wrong place. I think it must be counting commands that aren’t show all the time.

Are `Tag:="Save"` and `.Tag = "Save"` the same and what are they. 
What is `.Caption`? 
The above three parameters seem very similar.

```
Sub EditRightClickMenu()
'
'
'
   Dim cb As CommandBar
    Dim ctl As CommandBarButton
    On Error GoTo bye

    CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
    Set cb = CommandBars("Text")
    Set ctl = cb.FindControl(Tag:="Save")
    If ctl Is Nothing Then
        Set ctl = cb.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, _
            Before:=30, Temporary:=True)

        With ctl
            .Caption = "Save"
            .Tag = "Save"
            .FaceId = 3
            .BeginGroup = True
            .OnAction = "MySave"
        End With
    End If

bye:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Before:=30` is indeed the command on the menu before which you wish to insert the new control.  If you remove the line `On Error GoTo bye` line from your code and run it on a normal word install you'll get an error trying to set the line:

```
Set ctl = cb.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, _
        Before:=30, Temporary:=True)
```

This is because there aren't 30 controls on the default Text right click menu.  Change it to 5 and it'll work fine.

`Tag:="Save"` and `.Tag="Save"` are slightly different.  The `Tag:=` notation is used when specifying variable inputs to a method, in this case its the `Tag` input to the function of `FindControl`.  If you press Shift+F2 on your keyboard when selecting `FindControl` in you editor it'll take you to the definition of the method and all the variables.  The `.Tag` notation refers to an objects property, in this case the `Tag` is being set as `"Save"` so it can be found if the macro is run again.

Finally `.Caption` is merely the text displayed on the menu control once created.